# Repository of older package versions?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, thunderbird

Using Xubuntu 20.04.

Thunderbird 115 seems to use it's own window manager and themes, which clash with everything else.  I find it horridly ugly, so want to revert to Tbird 102.

However, all I can find in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/ is v102 for Ubuntu 18.04.  Similarly, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird does not have any history.

Is there an *actual* archive of older deb files?

Comment: open preferences scroll to windowlayout (i hope tranlation is correct) and untick the 1. option there.

Comment: Beware: Older releases of Thunderbird may be vulnerable to published exploits. See https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/thunderbird/

Comment: @nobody less bad (thanks!), but the *unread* counters are still harder to read.

Comment: @user535733 I'll take my chances with mostly irrelevant bugs in order to have a good looking mail client.

Comment: check in themes section that the 1. option is active (use system theme). At least in my debian give it the old view almost back.